# Problem installing ACS ACR38T (smart card reader) on Ubuntu 18.04-64

Tags: firefox, certificates

After struggling for a few hours, I thought it was time to ask the community. I am trying to install an ACS ACR38T Smart Card Reader on Ubuntu 18.04-64 (see https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/1/acr38t-d1-plug-in-sim-sized-card-reader/)

I can see it with lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 072f:90cc Advanced Card Systems, Ltd ACR38
```

I installed `libacsccid1`, `pcsc-tools` and `opensc` (via apt-get) and everything looks OK with the command `pcsc_scan`:

```
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.5.2 (c) 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00

Tue Sep  3 21:27:03 2019
 Reader 0: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted,
  ATR: 3B 7D 18 00 00 00 48 79 70 73 49 44 20 53 33 07 90 00

ATR: 3B 7D 18 00 00 00 48 79 70 73 49 44 20 53 33 07 90 00
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 7D, Y(1): 0111, K: 13 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 18 --> Fi=372, Di=12, 31 cycles/ETU
    129032 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 161290 bits/s
  TB(1) = 00 --> VPP is not electrically connected
  TC(1) = 00 --> Extra guard time: 0
+ Historical bytes: 00 48 79 70 73 49 44 20 53 33 07 90 00
  Category indicator byte: 00 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 4, len: 8 (initial access data)
      Initial access data: 79 70 73 49 44 20 53 33
    Mandatory status indicator (3 last bytes)
      LCS (life card cycle): 07 (Operational state (activated))
      SW: 9000 (Normal processing.)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 7D 18 00 00 00 48 79 70 73 49 44 20 53 33 07 90 00
    Safran Morpho YpsID S3
```

Unfortunately, when I load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so` as a new module in Firefox -> Security Devices, it shows:

```
Status: Not Present
Description: ACS ACR38U-CCID 00 00
Manufacturer: ACS
HW Version: 1.0
FW Version: 0.0
```

Basically, `pcsc_scan` sees the device as "Card inserted" but Firefox sees it as "Not Present" thus I can't use the certificate. I know it's not an hardware problem because the device works on a Windows 7 machine

Do you have any idea about what is happening?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same device (ACS ACR 38U-CCID) together with SuisseID. For unknown reasons I observe the same behavior like you. OpenSC can somehow work with the device, but Firefox can't.

To finally get it working with Firefox, I used a PKCS11 library from the vendor instead of the OpenSC PKCS11 library:

```
$ wget http://postsuisseid.ch/images/setup/postsuisseid-lin-1647.tar.bz2
$ tar xjf postsuisseid-lin-1647.tar.bz2
```

Now load `postsuisseid-lin-1647/lib_amd64/libcvP11.so` as a new security module into Firefox and you should be able to login and use your smart card.

For testing purposes to check if a PKCS11 library works or not, you can use these commands:

How it shouldn't be:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --verbose --test --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so 
No slot with a token was found.
```

How it should be:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --verbose --test --module postsuisseid-lin-1647/lib_amd64/libcvP11.so 
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x1)
C_SeedRandom() and C_GenerateRandom():
  seeding (C_SeedRandom) not supported
  seems to be OK
Digests:
  all 4 digest functions seem to work
  MD5: OK
  SHA-1: OK
  RIPEMD160: OK
Signature: not a R/W session, skipping signature tests
Verify: not a R/W session, skipping verify tests
Key unwrap: not a R/W session, skipping key unwrap tests
Decryption: not a R/W session, skipping decryption tests
No errors
```